# MySql Get Both records, But not all

Tags: mysql

I have this source data:

```
id  p_id    t_id
1   1       1
2   1       2
3   2       1
```

I want to see all of my products `p_id` that match serial numbers `t_id` 1 and 2 both. I do not want to see those products which have either `t_id` 1 or 2 alone. I also do not want to see repeated rows for each `p_id`.

I tried using this query:

```
select p_id, t_id from tbl_1 where t_id in (1 , 2)
```

but it returns:

```
id  p_id    t_id
1   1       1
2   1       2
3   2       1
```

I also tried the following but had no luck:

```
select p_id, t_id from tbl_1 where t_id = 1 and t_id = 2
```

Thanks.

Comment: I want to have only p_id with 1 value but i get 1 and 2 both.

Comment: protip: imagine what you might be able to do with the `and` operator

Comment: `select p_id, t_id from tbl_1 where t_id in ( 1 , 2) AND p_id=1`

Comment: Soory it was and not or, i edited my question.

Comment: t_id can never be 1 and 2 at the same time.

Comment: `where t_id = 1 and t_id = 2` is clearly wrong as it can't simultaneously be both

Comment: @ThinkDifferent, p_id is not known when firing query.

Comment: You need to explain it a bit more.

Comment: I just edited my question.

Comment: Assuming p_id is your product id then you have to use JOIN on tbl_1 and products table to get the results you need.

Comment: You have to select right by value in column you need. That's why you should change your query to this: select p_id, t_id from tbl_1 where p_id=1.

Comment: @AndrewSklyar, but my search is based on t_id and not on p_id.

Comment: With respect, this could have been greatly streamlined by wording your question more clearly, and demonstrating actual input and expected vs actual output.

Comment: I edited my question, Please check.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT id, p_id, t_id
FROM tbl_1
WHERE p_id IN (
   SELECT p_id
   FROM tbl_1 
   WHERE t_id IN (1 , 2)
   GROUP BY p_id
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t_id) = 2);
```

This will return all `tbl_1` rows, whose `p_id` values are related to *all* values of the `IN` operator, i.e. `(1 , 2)`.

If `IN` operator values are stored in another table, then the query can be modified to something like:

```
SELECT id, p_id, t_id
FROM tbl_1
WHERE p_id IN (
   SELECT p_id
   FROM tbl_1 
   WHERE t_id IN (SELECT id FROM temp)
   GROUP BY p_id
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t_id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp));
```

Comment: Nice! Could this be made 'dynamic' by replacing the `in` list with a query of another table (temp if desired) and the `= 2` with a `count` of the values in said table?

Comment: Since you're including my suggestions, shouldn't we use `count(distinct id) from temp` to avoid possible problems with duplicates/match the `distinct` on the left?

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary, as `temp` table is supposed to hold unique `id` values.

Comment: well, sure, but i like to think we all know how useful words like "should" and "supposed" really are when applied to human input! and it doesn't hurt to future-proof. but hey: it's your answer. ...kinda

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by` and `having`.  If you just want the `p_id`:

```
select p_id
from tbl_1
where t_id in (1 , 2)
group by p_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

Getting the `t_id` is not particularly interesting, but you can get them using `group_concat()`:

```
select p_id, group_concat(t_id)
from tbl_1
where t_id in (1 , 2)
group by p_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

Comment: Its not compulsory that count will be two. it can vary. 3,4 ,5 etc

Comment: then tell us what you actually want. what are `p` and `t`. what exactly do you want your query to return from the given input data, and why/what does that represent?

Comment: Consider, that i want my all products , that have serial no 1 & 2 both. And not those products which either have 1 or 2 or both.

Comment: @Purushottamzende . . . You need to construct the query.  Just like you would put the constants in the `IN` expression, you also need to set the `count(*)` to the number you are looking for.